# scrolling in a position fixed div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that is position: fixed. I am trying to scroll to an element inside that div.

```
$('.example').animate({
   scrollTop: $(".npwfu-ex").offset().top
}, 750);
```

Sometimes it scrolls to the right position. Sometimes not. How can I fix this?

Here's the CSS for the div with class "example":

```
.example {
   position: fixed;
   overflow: auto;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: add up a fiddle for this, for better understanding.

Comment: maybe use :
$(document).ready(function(){
code here...
});

Comment: Where is the HTML of your `.example` class? This could be something to do with setting `overflow-x or overflow-y`

Comment: There is not enough information here to get a minimal, complete, and verifiable example so at this point its all guessing. You need to show us how to exactly reproduce this behavior.

Comment: what you exactly want @brown po

Comment: provide your html codes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code if it works for you

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var objDiv = document.getElementById("you element id");
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
});
```

this code scroll down or scroll up to your div element

Comment: Explain your code it's not enough putting some code, you need to describe it.